# How to call PHP web service in Android application?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am developing an Android application in which all data come through PHP web service. Now I am confused that how to do this. Which web service(ksoap,soap,rest,etc) I should develop in PHP so that when I call that web service in Android it is light-weight? And what things I Need to do for this type of application? Also currently I am making application locally so PHP will get data from mysql database. Please suggest which web service I should develop. How do I call it in Android application? Also I want to know that is there anyway that I can develop web service in Android itself because I have only static data to pass and might be 2 or 3 data in will be needed to enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need small data and that is also locally, so better to go for REST as it doesn't need any extra stuff like KSOAP or anything else.If distributed environment is there, then SOAP is better.In your case i think REST is good.

[Here](http://davidwalsh.name/web-service-php-mysql-xml-json) is an link you can check.

Comment: Can REST works for fetching data from database? I mean I am not using online website data. I am using just local data from my laptop.

Comment: @Dhwani You have webservice, that will return you data fetching from database,so u have to implement that in webservice.u can see that in the link i have provided.and you have to get that data inside ur android prpject and parse it either using json parsing technique or xmlparsing technique.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I gone through your site. It helped me. But I have little query that is it basic web service but of what type(REST/SOAP)?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest you to use SOAP, it's not comfortable, to implement.
I have spent much time to parse these element that come from SOAP services, i suggest you to implement `JSON` webservice.

```
    /*web service parameters*/
    private static final String TAG = RestSearchResultList.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetSomething";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetSomething";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.yoursite.com /Services/webservice.asmx";
```

invocation of service:

```
private SoapObject CallWebService() {
    try {
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("lang", Language);
            request.addProperty("restTitle", mSearchText);          
            request.addProperty("x", mLongitude);
            request.addProperty("y", mLatitude);


            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
            md.register(envelope);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            SearchingMap.getInstance().Clear();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
}
```

this is only to invoke the service, without parsing it and stuff.

JSON example:

```
  public class AsyncJsonDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, JSONArray> {
    private JsonLoader _jsonHelper;
    private IJsonDataListener _dataListener;
    private ProgressDialog _dialog;

    /*Progress bar widget initialize*/
    public AsyncJsonDataTask(IJsonDataListener dataListener, ProgressDialog dialog) {
        _dataListener = dataListener;
        _jsonHelper = new JsonLoader();
        _dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {
        JSONArray result = _jsonHelper.GetJSONArray(urls[0]);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
        if (_dialog != null) {
            if (_dialog.isShowing()) {
                _dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        _dataListener.OnJsonDataLoadComplete(result); //gets data oncomplete
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (_dialog != null) {
            _dialog.setMessage("Load Data");
            _dialog.show();
        }
    }
}

public class JsonHelper {
    /* public static Object toJSON(Object object) throws JSONException {
            if (object instanceof Map) {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                Map map = (Map) object;
                for (Object key : map.keySet()) {
                    json.put(key.toString(), toJSON(map.get(key)));
                }
                return json;
            } else if (object instanceof Iterable) {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
                for (Object value : ((Iterable)object)) {
                    json.put(value);
                }
                return json;
            } else {
                return object;
            }
        }

        public static boolean isEmptyObject(JSONObject object) {
            return object.names() == null;
        }

        public static Map<String, Object> getMap(JSONObject object, String key) throws JSONException {
            return toMap(object.getJSONObject(key));
        }

        public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap();
            Iterator keys = object.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String) keys.next();
                map.put(key, fromJson(object.get(key)));
            }
            return map;
        }

        public static List toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
            List list = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                list.add(fromJson(array.get(i)));
            }
            return list;
        }

        private static Object fromJson(Object json) throws JSONException {
            if (json == JSONObject.NULL) {
                return null;
            } else if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
                return toMap((JSONObject) json);
            } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
                return toList((JSONArray) json);
            } else {
                return json;
            }
        }*/
}
```

I have written this once in whole project no configs and stuff, i preserved `SRP` here, you can check what you need and use it.